# Autohotkey: remap dead key+letter combination

Tags: windows, keyboard, vnc, autohotkey

I'm trying to use Autohotkey to map <kbd>´</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to something different than the `á` that is expected in my Spanish keyboard.

[This thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/61700-how-to-detect-if-a-deadkey-is-pressed/) gives me the impression that it is not possible, but I'm just a Autohotkey newbie.

**Background**

I want to do that, and several more similar combinations [trying to survive the hell of reaching a Mac machine from a Windows one through VNC](https://serverfault.com/questions/16637/is-there-a-vnc-server-for-mac-with-decent-international-keyboard-support)

**Edit with additonnal info**

This is the key history displayed by AutoHotkey

```
VK  SC    Up/Down Elapsed Key
---------------------------------------
DE  028   d       3.74    ´                 
DE  028   u       0.16    ´                 
41  01E   d       0.25    A                 
41  01E   u       0.11    A
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't map a dead key directly; they are so called because they don't send a keycode to the system, but just notify the keyboard's microcontroller to possibly do something unusual with the next character typed.

What you probably *can* do, though, is map `á` itself; you may need to do a little hunting around to find the keycode (the AHK documentation keycode list is [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm), and a script that shows keycodes of pressed keys can be found [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21105-crazy-scripting-scriptlet-to-find-scancode-of-a-key/) -- I'm not sure how accurate that last one is, but you can probably make something of it. Also, if you open the main script window from its system tray icon, then click "View -> Key History", you'll see a list of keys the script has seen pressed, which may well give you the keycode.

Anyway, once you know how to refer to a particular accented character in your scripts, you can map it to a fare-thee-well, just as with anything else on your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks! I added the Key History: it would be great if you could give me a hint of what should I be trying with them...

Comment: Wow! That dead key's not dead at all. Since it's got a scan code of its own, you can map just the dead key via the `SCxxx` form described in http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys -- to map the combination of both keys entails essentially treating the dead key as a custom modifier key, which I haven't done before but this advice looks good: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85649-turning-any-key-into-a-modifier/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. `~SC028 & a:: blablabla` sort of works. Sort of. The usual way to type an accented char is press and release <kbd>´</kbd> and then press and release <kbd>a</kbd>. This only works if <kbd>´</kbd> is kept pressed, and I don't think I will be able to convince my fingers that this is the proper way to type accented chars

Comment: Fair enough. So I can be sure I understand what you're after -- you're looking to have the same key sequence (`'`, then `a`) produce the same result (`á`) on the OS X machine you're accessing remotely, as it does on the Windows machine you're sitting in front of, right? If so, I think I can see a way to do that, but it'd be every bit as ugly as complex AutoHotKey scripts always are...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. No need to get into ugly scripts for me: I ended up finding a VNC server/viewer combo that dealt properly with international keyboards out of the box (RealVNC)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:*:á::
SoundBeep, 500, 500
Return
```

B.t.w. I use these accented characters, but without using the international keyboard setting, but by using ahk This way I have full control (and no dead keys)
The only problem is that this key will no longer work when used alone, it will function inside a word.

Comment: Thanks. Did not work. `:*:e::` makes a beep, while `:*:á::` or `:*:´a::` do not.

Comment: Wow, this is unexpected. Thank you for the feedback. I checked it now and am stunned my self.

Comment: I'd have expected it to work as well, but looking at the key history output in the post, AutoHotkey seems to be seeing the "dead" key separately from the 'a' key. Very strange.